# jqGrid version 4.3.1 Advanced search dialog not appearing as popup

Tags: jqgrid

Hi updgraded my jqGrid from version 4 to 4.3.1 and noticed that the pop up window for the advanced search is now appearing in line on the page. I want the pop up behaviour. Any body encountered this problem?

Comment: You should include as least the list of CSS and JS from the HTML page. What you mean exactly with "in line on the page"? Do you have the results like on the picture from [the page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) or not? In any way one need more information about *how* you use jqGrid to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but my assumption is that you are getting the toolbar search functionality, instead a popup search dialog (single or advanced search). You did not post any code, so it's hard to know what is going on, and I can only guess.

Do you happen to utilize the beforeShowSearch event? If yes, one breaking change I noticed in recent versions of jqGrid is that you must now return true from the event handler if you want the search dialog to pop up. If you return anything other than true, the dialog does not get displayed.